# Can't change the text size in programmatically created UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, text, uilabel, size

I cannot change the size of the text in a programmatically created `UILabel`.

Here's a screen grab:

[image: screen grab]

Here's the class definition:

```
class myView: UIView {
    let theLabel = UILabel()

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.theLabel.text = "Text"
        self.theLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

        self.theLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        self.theLabel.textAlignment = .center
        self.theLabel.numberOfLines = 1
        self.theLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.1
        self.theLabel.font = UIFont( name: "System", size:160)
        self.theLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.addSubview(self.theLabel)

        let selfAspectConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

        let labelWidthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.theLabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width, multiplier: 0.5, constant: 0)

        let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.theLabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self.theLabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width, multiplier: 0.5, constant: 0)

        let xConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.theLabel, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

        let yConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.theLabel, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

        self.addConstraints([selfAspectConstraint,labelWidthConstraint, heightConstraint,xConstraint,yConstraint])
    }
    /*
    // Only override draw() if you perform custom drawing.
    // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        // Drawing code
    }
    */
}
```

I've tried changing the font size. I've set `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` to true and set `minimumScaleFactor`. The text size is always the same. I expect it to fill the label area, the grey box.

How do I get this to work?

Comment: ， how do you create the `myView`?

Comment: I think the reason @aircraft is asking is because you've coded everything in init(coder:), not init(frame:).

Comment: in IB. I added a UIView and set the class to myView

Comment: Try to move the code to a viewDidLoad method. Does it work correctly here?

Comment: @Avt, the only code he has shown us is in a UIView subclass, which doesn't have a viewDidLoad - but it's view controller does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try adding this line after you set the font:
self.theLabel.font = theLabel.font.withSize(45)

Comment: This does work! Thanks! Why do I need to explicitly set the font size? I set a size when I assigned the font.

Comment: Maybe there is no font named "System". Also try

Comment: self.theLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 80)

Comment: It's silly and completely bananas - but this is the only way iOS 10 allows me to use a tiny font (e.g. `9`) when creating `UILabel` instances from code! Going bonkers......

Answer (score 0):

Your code works as expected, without any change.[image]
[image]

> CustomView1NoXIB.swift

```
import UIKit
class CustomView1NoXIB : UIView {
  let theLabel = UILabel()

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    initSubviews()
  }




  func initSubviews() {
    self.theLabel.text = "Hello"
//    self.theLabel.text = "Hello World Big Text Becomes Small"
    self.theLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

    self.theLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    self.theLabel.textAlignment = .center
    self.theLabel.numberOfLines = 1
    self.theLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.1
    self.theLabel.font = UIFont( name: "System", size:160)
    self.theLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.addSubview(self.theLabel)

    let selfAspectConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

    let labelWidthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.theLabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width, multiplier: 0.5, constant: 0)

    let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.theLabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self.theLabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width, multiplier: 0.5, constant: 0)

    let xConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.theLabel, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

    let yConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.theLabel, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

    self.addConstraints([selfAspectConstraint,labelWidthConstraint, heightConstraint,xConstraint,yConstraint])

  }
}
```

> CustomView1ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit
class CustomView1ViewController : UIViewController {
  @IBOutlet weak var customView1: CustomView1!
  @IBOutlet weak var customView1NoXIB: CustomView1NoXIB!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  }
}
```

Thanks,
Sriram

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sriram. I was trying to make the text large, to fill the frame. David Lindsay's answer works, though I don't know why.